# Stretch Image for a table in asp.net

Tags: css, image, css-tables

I have a table, and I am using an image as background.

Now my requirement is, if my table's height or width is bigger than that of image, I do not want the image to repeat (Current Situation).

Instead I would love to stretch my image. By the way using the table as a custom web-part in SharePoint 2010.

**CSS** used:

```
.style1
    {
        width: 600px;
        height: 366px;
        float: left;
        background-image: url('../../../_layouts/images/tableMSHU1.bmp');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `background-size` attribute.

```
background-size:600px 366px;
```

Comment: Good one AVD, however the table size is likely to change, if we add more rows or columns !! Would like to see the image stretches dynamically !!

Comment: Hi I did not get any update for this so I aligned the image to middle!!